# Proving an inequality for $\sinh$ and $\cosh$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

I want to prove that:

$$\frac{1}{4}\cosh(t)+p^4+2p^2+\frac{\sinh^2(t)}{r^2}\le\frac{1}{4}\cosh^2(t)$$ for all $t\ge 0$ and for $a>0$ large enough.

Where $r=\sqrt{1+4a}$, $p=\frac{2\sqrt{a}}{r}$

We have 
$$\frac{1}{4}\cosh(t)+\frac{16a^2}{(1+4a)^2}+2\frac{4a}{(1+4a)}+\frac{\sinh^2(t)}{(1+4a)}\le\frac{1}{4}\cosh^2(t)$$
is equivalent to
$$\frac{1}{4}\cosh(t)(1+4a)^2+16a^2+8a(1+4a)+\sinh^2(t)(1+4a)\le\frac{1}{4}\cosh^2(t)(1+4a)^2$$

is equivalent to
$$\frac{1}{4}\cosh(t)(1+4a)^2+16a^2+8a(1+4a)+(\cosh^2(t)-1)(1+4a)\le\frac{1}{4}\cosh^2(t)(1+4a)^2$$

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: You surely have tried to plug the expressions of $r$ and $p$ in the inequality, no ? Why don't you show us ?

Comment: I wrote $\frac{1}{4}\cosh(t)+p^4+2p^2+\frac{\sinh^2(t)}{r^2}\le\frac{1}{4}\cosh(t)+3+\sinh^2(t)$ since $p\le 1$ and $r\ge 1$. But i didn't find the result

Comment: That doesn't answer my question: an evident transformation is certainly to replace the two parameters $r,p$ by the single parameter $a$ !

Comment: Ok you mean $$\frac{1}{4}\cosh(t)+\frac{16a^2}{(1+4a)^2}+2\frac{4a}{(1+4a)}+\frac{\sinh^2(t)}{(1+4a)}\le\frac{1}{4}\cosh^2(t)$$ is equivalent to $$\frac{1}{4}\cosh(t)(1+4a)^2+16a^2+8a(1+4a)+\sinh^2(t)(1+4a)\le\frac{1}{4}\cosh^2(t)(1+4a)^2$$ is equivalent to $$\frac{1}{4}\cosh(t)(1+4a)^2+16a^2+8a(1+4a)+(cosh^2(t)-1)(1+4a)\le\frac{1}{4}\cosh^2(t)(1+4a)^2$$and then how i conclude ?

Comment: Well, that's a quadratic polynomial in $x=\cosh t$, and it has to be $\ge0$, at least for all $x\ge1$. Looks like a not so difficult task.

Comment: $$\frac{1}{4}\cosh(t)(1+4a)^2+\frac{1}{4}\Big(16a^2+8a(1+4a)+(cosh^2(t)-1)(1+4a)\Big)\le\frac{1}{4}\cosh^2(t)(1+4a)^2$$ is equivalent to $$\cosh(t)(1+4a)^2+\Big(16a^2+8a(1+4a)+(cosh^2(t)-1)(1+4a)\Big)\le\cosh^2(t)(1+4a)^2$$ is equivalent to $$0\le\cosh^2(t)\Big((1+4a)^2-(1+4a)\Big)-\cosh(t)(1+4a)^2+(1+4a)-\Big(16a^2+8a(1+4a))$$ we note $x=ch(t)$, the inéquality is equivalent to $$0\le x^2\Big((1+4a)^2-(1+4a)\Big)-x(1+4a)^2+(1+4a)-\Big(16a^2+8a(1+4a)\Big)$$

Comment: but how did you prove that the final iniquality is true? i don't sea that clearly, $\Delta= (1+4a)^4 +4\Big((1+4a)^2-(1+4a)\Big)\Big(48a^2+4a-1\Big)$$

Comment: $\Delta\ge 0$ if $a\ge0$ and then the inequality is true for all $t\ge 0$ and all $a\ge 0$ ? is that right?

Answer (score 0):

Something isn't right in the formulation of the problem, insofar as it wants the inequality to hold for all $t\ge0$ and "for $a\gt0$ large enough."  Set $t=0$ in the inequality.  This gives

$${1\over4}+p^4+2p^2\le{1\over4}$$

But this clearly cannot hold unless $p=0$, which is not the case.

Comment: exactly you are right I want to find $t_0>0$ such that the inéquality is true for all $t\ge t_0$

Comment: @aymen, the existence of such a $t_0$ is fairly straightforward as soon as $r\gt2$, since the cosh *squared* on the right hand side will grow much faster than the left side.

Comment: i don't sea that crearly can you please explan with more deteils?

Answer (score 0):

Replacing $$\frac1{r^2}=1-p^2$$ one is left to show that for every $t$, and for every $p<1$ close enough to $1$, one has $$\frac{1}{4}\cosh(t)+p^4+2p^2+(1-p^2)\sinh^2(t)\leqslant\frac{1}{4}\cosh^2(t)$$ or equivalently,
that, for every $x<1$ close enough to $1$, $$u(t,x)\leqslant0$$ where $$u(t,x)=\cosh(t)+4x^2+8x+4(1-x)\sinh^2(t)-\cosh^2(t)$$
Now, it happens that $$u(t,1)=\cosh(t)+12-\cosh^2(t)=-(\cosh t-4)(\cosh t+3)$$ is negative for every $t$ large enough (say, every $t\geqslant2.1$) hence there is no way that the desired inequality can hold for every $p<1$, $p$ close to $1$, if $t$ is large.

Comment: @ Did, we have the same result if we consider $$2ch(t)+p^4+2p^2+\frac{sh^2(t)}{r^2}\le ch^2(t)$$?

Comment: **Tell me...** $ $

Comment: i think it is also false but how to prove that?

Comment: Grab a pen and start computing.

Comment: by using the same method?

Comment: in this cas $$u(t,x)=2ch(t)+x^2+2x+sh^2(t)(1-x)-ch^2(t)$$ so $$u(t,1)=2ch(t)+3-ch^2(t)=-(ch(t)-3)(ch(t)-1)$$  which is negative for $t$ large enought